# Is it possible to upgrade the Samsung Slate 7 SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, upgrade, slate

I have a Samsung Slate 7 (XE700T1A-A06US) with an internal 128GB mSATA (SAMSUNG MZMPA128HMFU) Solid State Drive (SSD), and have run out of room on the drive.  I’d like to upgrade the drive to something larger (e.g., 500GB SSD).  Has anyone successfully upgraded one of these SSDs already, and if so what SSD was compatible?

Comment: Hi Ramhound, I appreciate your help with this.  I haven't had much experience with SSDs.  Like you, I believe the mSATA standard will ensure the SSD interfaces are compatible.  I'm also concerned about whether or not the older Samsung BIOS will support the larger SSD and if the new SSD will fit in the same Slate 7 SSD space?

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up....  After much research and a little trial & error, for ~$300, I successfully migrated my Samsung Slate 7 (XE700T1A) from it's original 128GB SAMSUNG mSATA (MZMPA128HMFU) SSD to a new Samsung 860 EVO mSATA SSD.  Along with the new 500GB SSD, I also purchased a Sabrent mSATA external enclosure, and the Acronis cloning software.

Once I installed the 500GB SSD into the Sabrent mSATA external enclosure, I connected it to the Samsung Slate via a USB cable.  Then ran the Acronis software for Windows, ran the cloning app in it's default settings mode and it successfully cloned the 128GB SSD onto the 500GB SSD the first time. In doing so, Acronis successfully migrated the 128GB SSD's hidden system recovery partition, the system / boot & and main partition, and the hidden partition where disk recovery images were stored.

Since both SSDs were made by Samsung, I tried to use the Samsung cloning software, but it wasn't able to recognize both SSDs.

Comment: It appears you accidentally created another account. Please read [this help article](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to get them merged. Then, remember to accept your answer so this question is marked as answered.